# Relation between singular values of matrices and their products

Tags: matrices

Is there any explicit relation between the singular values $\lambda_X$ and $\lambda_Y$ of two same size matrices $X$ and $Y$, respectively, and the singular values $\lambda_{XY^t}$ of the matrix $XY^t$?
Otherwise said, is there a function $f$ such that $\lambda_{XY^t}=f(\lambda_X , \lambda_Y)$?

Thank you
Riadh

Comment: What is $\lambda_X$ for a given matrix $X$?

Answer (score 2):

Denote the $i$-th largest singular value of a matrix $A$ by $\sigma_i(A)$. Then for any two complex $m\times n$ matrices, we have the following inequality:
$$
\sigma_{i+j-1}(XY^\ast)\le\sigma_i(X)\sigma_j(Y) \ \text{ when }\ i+j\le\min(m,n)+1.
$$
See p.423 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*, Cambridge University Press.

As matrices are *not* completely characterized by their singular values, it is hard to believe that the singular values of $XY^T$ in general can be expressed as a function of the singular values of $X$ and $Y$. For example, consider $X=\operatorname{diag}(1,0),\,Y_1=X$ and $Y_2=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$. Then $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have identical singular values but $XY_1^T$ and $XY_2^T$ do not.

Comment: A good answer, but I want to point out that matrices are also not completely characterized by their determinants, and yet $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.