# Singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to ask a question about singular values of matrices of the form $A^TA$. We know that by Courant minimax principle the singular values are given by (in increasing order $s_1 > s_2...>s_n$

$(s_i)^2 = min_{\{V | dim(V) \geq n-i+1\}}max_{\{x | |x|=1, x \in V\}}\{|Ax|\}$

Also by Cauchy interlacing property if we have an operator like B = A.P (were P is a projection) then we can relate the singular value of B to that of A since

$B^TB = PA^TAP$

so that singular values of B and A may be compared through Cauchy interlacing property. However what I have information about is the operator B=P.A (where P is a projection) and the singular values of this operator are related to eigenvalues of $A^T.P.P.A = A.P.A$. Is there anyway to relate the eigenvalues of $A^T.P.A$ to $A^TA$.

i.) I know that there are bounds for singular values of product of matrices of the form for instance given in

[Relation between singular values of matrices and their products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270334/relation-between-singular-values-of-matrices-and-their-products)

but they do not turn out to be good for me.

ii.) Trying $B.B^T$ does not also help since then I would need information about $A^T.P$ which I dont have.

I would be grateful if you could direct me at such theorems as Cauchy interlacing property that might be related to this, if there are any ofcourse. Thanks